# newman report without timestamp

Tags: newman, postman-newman

I using newman in docker and I need that when generating a report timestamp is not added to the name
Newman as such does not have this parameter in it.

```
docker run -v ~/collections:/etc/newman -t postman/newman run "https://www.getpostman.com/collections/8a0c9bc08f062d12dcda" --verbose --reporters json,cli
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a html reporter supported by newman where we can get the timestamp appended to the report file name.

Below link is having the full documentation
https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/generate-advanced-html-reports-while-using-newman/

Sample command

```
f"newman run {collection} --reporters=cli,htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export {extract_path}/newman-report/"
```

[image]